# Which event to use in order to execute a function after a frontend order?

Tags: php, module

Which event should I use in order to execute a function after a frontend order? In other module, a colleague used  but I think this is for backend orders.

Comment: Which is your Magento version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to execute function after order is created use `sales_order_place_after` event.

If you want to execute function only when order is successful use `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` event.

if you want to use event for frontend,backend also write the event in the `<global>` tag in the config.xml

```
<global>
    <events>
        <sales_order_place_after></sales_order_place_after>
        <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action></checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
    </events>
</global>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` event. It will be called after the order is placed on frontend i.e. when the customer is redirected to the checkout success page